# Can't Access Magento Through WAN

Tags: magento2, xampp

I've just installed magento 2 based on Windows using Xampp .. and it is working fine. my problem is, i purchased a domain name for it and put it in httpd-vhosts but i can't access it from outside (WAN).

**Note:** i can access the xampp dashboard page through https://domainname/dashboard but when i type  https://domainname/magento to access magento it is loading for 1-2 Mins and change the url in the browser to the localip! like this: `http://localhost/magento` and for sure i can't access Magento server local IP or  localhost from outside
I think there is an issue in file located in magento folder that cause the redirection problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check secure/unsecure base url in core_config_data table.

Comment: i configure it to be http://localip/magento and configure a vhost in apache server using ProxyPass as the below:-

<VirtualHost *:443>
      ServerName     mydomain.com
      ServerAlias    www.mydomain.com

    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyPass / http://localhost/magento
SSLEngine on
      SSLCertificatefile "conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"
      SSLCertificatekeyfile "conf/ssl.key/server.key"
  </VirtualHost>